# jquery find and replace keywords in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to loop through and find and replace certain words in a elements? here is what ive tried but not playing ball.

example of html:

```
<div class="homepage-boxes">
    <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Shop Interior Bean Bags</h2>
    <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Shop Outdoor Bean Bags</h2>
    <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Buy Kids Bean Bags</h2>
    <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Buy Baby Bean Bags</h2>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('.homepage-boxes .ty-mainbox-simple-title').each(function() {
    $(this).html().replace('Shop','');
    $(this).html().replace('Buy','');
    $(this).html().replace('Bean Bags','');
});
```

expected output:

```
<div class="homepage-boxes">
    <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Interior</h2>
    <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Outdoor</h2>
    <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Kids</h2>
    <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Baby</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to reset it `$(this).html($(this).html().replace('Shop',''))`

Comment: Gave that a try but did not seem to do the trick, actually getting this error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: please check my answer. run snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, even though you are replacing the contents, the html is not set back to the element.

You can use the setter version of `.html()` with a regex replace like

```js
$('.homepage-boxes .ty-mainbox-simple-title').html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/Shop|Buy|Bean Bags/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="homepage-boxes">
  <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Shop Interior Bean Bags</h2>
  <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Shop Outdoor Bean Bags</h2>
  <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Buy Kids Bean Bags</h2>
  <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Buy Baby Bean Bags</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `reset` html after `replace`

```js
$('.homepage-boxes .ty-mainbox-simple-title').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Shop','').replace('Buy','').replace('Bean Bags',''));
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="homepage-boxes">
    <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Shop Interior Bean Bags</h2>
    <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Shop Outdoor Bean Bags</h2>
    <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Buy Kids Bean Bags</h2>
    <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Buy Baby Bean Bags</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: i will in 7 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

you will have to put the replaced string into the h2 to show the results

```js
$('.homepage-boxes').find('h2.ty-mainbox-simple-title').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Shop', ''));
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Buy', ''));
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Bean Bags', ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="homepage-boxes">
  <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Shop Interior Bean Bags</h2>
  <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Shop Outdoor Bean Bags</h2>
  <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Buy Kids Bean Bags</h2>
  <h2 class="ty-mainbox-simple-title">Buy Baby Bean Bags</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.homepage-boxes .ty-mainbox-simple-title').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text( $this.text().replace('Shop','') );
    $this.text( $this.text().replace('Buy','') );
    $this.text( $this.text().replace('Bean Bags','') );
});
```